# nested eager loading returns only 1 record

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize that it's query that it
produces returns all the records in a postgresql
query.
The sequelize however returns only 1 record.

The query:

```
_db.Treatment.findOne({
    where: {
        treatment_autoid: req.treatment_id
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: _db.TreatmentSection,            
        include:
          {
            model: _db.TreatmentSectionChannel,
          },            
      },
```

Comment: `findOne`seems to be pretty verbose about what it does.

Answer (score 0):

if you change `findOne` to `findAll` makes your problem solved!

`findOne` includes limit 1 so it returns just one object!

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't about returning just one by findOne, its because return just one in the nested Schema.